# Bot Exclusion discord.py

Tags: discord.py

How can I make my Bot Exclude someone from the usage if a user's abusing it (like spamming commands and stuff)

````py
@client.command(pass_context = True, aliases = ['bban'])
@commands.is_owner()
async def botban(ctx, member: discord.Member = None, banreason='Kein Grund angegeben!'):
    if member is None:
        em = discord.Embed(color = 0xff2200, title = "Argumente Fehlen!",
                           description = f"{ctx.author.mention} Bitte nenne den User, den du vom Bot ausschließen willst\n\n```py\no?botban [@nutzer / id] [(optional) Grund]\n```\n Optional: ```py\no?bban [@nutzer / id] [(optional) Grund]\n```",
                           footer = f'User-ID: ' + str(ctx.author.id) + ' Made by Ohnezahn DNC#8135 with discord.py')
        em.set_author(name = f'{ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator}',
                      icon_url = f'{ctx.message.author.avatar_url}')
        return await ctx.send(embed = em)

    elif message.author.id in 'blacklist.json':  # Check if user already banned
        return await ctx.send(
            f"Der Nutzer {member.id} / {member.name} - {member.discriminator} ist bereits ausgeschlossen! Grund:\n\n{banreason}")

    elif member.id not in 'ban.json':
        with open('ban.json', 'w') as fp:
            json.dump(banlist, fp)
            emb = discord.Embed(color = 0xff2200, title = "Bot Ban ausgeführt",
                                description = f'{member.mention} / {member.name}#{member.discriminator} / {member.id} wurde von {ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator} / {ctx.author.id} / {ctx.author.mention} vom Bot ausgeschlossen\n\nGrund: {banreason}',
                                footer = f'User-ID: ' + str(member.id) + '/ Made by Ohnezahn DNC#8135 with discord.py')
            emb.set_author(name = f'{ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator}',
                           icon_url = f'{ctx.message.author.avatar_url}')
        return await ctx.send(embed = emb)
    else:
        # Add ban to dict
        banlist[member.id] = banreason

        # Update File
        with open('ban.json', 'w') as fp:
            json.dump(banlist, fp)

        emb = discord.Embed(color = 0xff2200, title = "Bot Ban ausgeführt",
                            description = f'{member.mention} / {member.name}#{member.discriminator} / {member.id} wurde von {ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator} / {ctx.author.id} / {ctx.author.mention} vom Bot ausgeschlossen\n\nGrund: {banreason}',
                            footer = f'User-ID: ' + str(member.id) + '/ Made by Ohnezahn DNC#8135 with discord.py')
        emb.set_author(name = f'{ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator}',
                       icon_url = f'{ctx.message.author.avatar_url}')
        return await ctx.send(embed = emb)


@client.check
def check_commands(ctx):
    # Check if user banned, convert id to str because json.load (line 9) load str id's.
    return str(ctx.author.id) not in blacklisted_users()
````

That's how my ban.json looks like at the moment:

```json
{
    "blacklistedUsers": [
    ]
}
```

that's the codes I have right now... I'm working on this for felt ages right now...

Comment: What's the purpose of those `assert` statements? Everything in python is an object, it will always be `True`

Comment: Welcome to Stack! The simplest way to go about it would be to create a `json`, then whenever this command is run you can use a [Global Check](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#global-checks) to check if the user is in it. You can read more about using json [in the linked docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) if you'd like to

Comment: An easier alternative would be to use a cooldown

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński cooldown != bot exclusion... it just makes the user wait until he / she may use the command again

Answer (score 0):

Hello welcome to Stack overflow, There are something in commands called checks. You could add an array the check can see if the user is in that array. If it is don't let them run the command by stopping the command using return

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

You can do similar thing:

```
import discord, json
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', intents=intents)

# Load banned data from json
with open('ban.json') as json_file:
    bot.banneds = json.load(json_file)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user} (ID: {bot.user.id})')
    print('------')

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx): # Only random command for test
    await ctx.send("Test okay!")

@bot.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member = None, banreason = 'Empty Reason'):
    if member.id in bot.banneds: # Check if user already banned
        await ctx.send("Already banned.")
        return
    else:
        # Add ban to dict
        bot.banneds[member.id] = banreason

        # Update File
        with open('ban.json', 'w') as fp:
            json.dump(bot.banneds, fp)

        await ctx.send(f"{member} has been banned, because {banreason}!")
    
# Ban Check (Global)
@bot.check
def check_commands(ctx):
    # Check if user banned, convert id to str because json.load (line 9) load str id's.
    return str(ctx.author.id) not in bot.banneds

bot.run('key')
```

Create a ban.json at the first time with empty object

```
{}
```

Note that if user banned try use commands, you receive error "discord.ext.commands.errors.CheckFailure: The global check functions for command test failed.", add this to your error handler.

Comment: well... used it, that's the output:

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/823168666237534248/860943211794923520/unknown.png

Comment: line 316, change banned to banneds, with s.

Comment: welp... https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/856891800845418520/860974550241247232/unknown.png